# Two eth devices, two subnets, pfsense and VM

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization

From my laptop in 192.168.1.0/24 network I am able to ping a host (VM) in 192.168.2.0/24 network but I am unable to ping the same host (VM) using its second ethernet device in 192.168.100.0/24 network.

```
laptop       pfsense    VM host                    VM
.1.116/24 -- .1.20/24   -- bond1 .1.2/24  
             .2.20/24   -- bond1.2/br2 .2.2/24     -- ens3 .2.7/24
             .100.20/24 -- bond1.100/br100 .100/24 -- ens9 .100.7/24
```

I've been scratching my head for some time on this so any ideas would be much appreciated

I've got a VM with two network interfaces:

- ens3: 192.168.2.7/24
- ens9: 192.168.100.7/24

route -n produces:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.20    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 ens3
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 ens9
```

PFSense is default gateway for 192.168.{1,2,100}.0/24 networks and it has 
192.168.{1,2,100}.20 IP addresses.  Firewall rules are configured in that way that it allows all IPv4 traffic on all networks, basically on each network: 192.168.{1,2.10}/24 it has rule defined:

```
protocol source port destination port gateway queue
IPV4*    *      *    *           *    *       none
```

On my laptop 192.168.1.116 the route -n produces:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.20    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp59s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp59s0
```

On the host that runs VM i have got interfaces configured as follow:

```
auto bond1
iface bond1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.20
  # following by bonding configuration, etc 

auto bond1.2
iface bond1.2 inet manual
  vlan-raw-device bond1

auto br2
iface br2 inet static
  address 192.168.2.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bridge_ports bond1.2

auto bond1.100
iface bond1.100 inet manual
  vlan-raw-device bond1

auto br100
iface br100 inet static
  address 192.168.100.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bridge_ports bond1.100
```

iptables on all hosts:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: I'd check ethtool for all interfaces, to make sure there isn't a fundamental issue. Also check the bond config. Otherwise the routes and gateways look fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to ping both interfaces on VM host: 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.100.2 I configured iproute2 in following way:

on hypervisor (192.168.1.2, 192.168.2.2, 192.168.100.2):

```
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
2 rt_lan2
100 rt_lan100
```

Following by configuration of routes/rules in the following way

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev br2 src 192.168.2.2 table rt_lan2
ip route add default via 192.168.2.20 dev br2 table rt_lan2
ip rule add from 192.168.2.2/32 table rt_lan2
ip rule add to 192.168.2.2/32 table rt_lan2

ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev br100 src 192.168.100.2 table rt_lan100
ip route add default via 192.168.100.20 dev br100 table rt_lan100
ip rule add from 192.168.100.2/32 table rt_lan100
ip rule add to 192.168.100.2/32 table rt_lan100
```

on vm (192.168.2.7, 192.168.100.7)

```
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
2 rt_lan2
100 rt_lan100
```

following by

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev ens3 src 192.168.2.7 table rt_lan2
ip route add default via 192.168.2.20 dev ens3 table rt_lan2
ip rule add from 192.168.2.7/32 table rt_lan2
ip rule add to 192.168.2.7/32 table rt_lan2

ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev ens9 src 192.168.100.7 table rt_lan100
ip route add default via 192.168.100.20 dev ens9 table rt_lan100
ip rule add from 192.168.100.7/32 table rt_lan100
ip rule add to 192.168.100.7/32 table rt_lan100
```

Inspired by [excellent article](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System)